# Get all field names in Microsoft Access Table using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

How do I get all the field names in a Table in Microsoft Access using JET SQL?

Thanks all

Comment: This is not possible in pure SQL.

Comment: Are you not able to use VBA for this purpose?

Comment: Uh, VBA != SQL. Of course, you can use VBA, or C# or VB.NET or vbScript or any language you want as long as it can connect to a driver that can read your Jet database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making using of the ODBC extension in PHP and it has a function to do this!

In case anyone needs this in the future its, [**odbc_tables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-tables.php)!

Comment: I do need it, but for Perl, and its DBD::ODBC doesn't appear to support an equivalent.

Comment: For python if you are using pyodbc check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328498.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [sometablename] WHERE 1<>1 or
SELECT * FROM [sometablename] WHERE 1=2
```

This will result no row data but with field names.